# Cannot call value of non-function type 'DrawCircleSegment'

Tags: swift, compiler-errors, swiftui

As a beginning programmer, I've tried many solutions to the following problem, but none seem to work. Also, the answers provided in this forum appear too complicated for me to be helpful. So, help would be appreciated. Also trying to understand why this piece will not compile, whereas if I fill in hard-coded values, it will.

```
    struct ContentView: View {
        static let segmentCount = 2
        var DrawArc = DrawCircleSegment()
        var body: some View {

            VStack {
                ForEach(1..<ContentView.segmentCount){ i in
                    DrawArc(r: CGFloat(50.0 * i), center_x: 100.0, center_y: 100,   arc_start: 0, arc_end: 90, arc_width: 30)
                }
            }
        }
    }
struct DrawCircleSegment: View {
    let r: CGFloat
    var center_x: CGFloat
    var center_y: CGFloat
    var arc_start: Angle
    var arc_end: Angle
    var arc_width: CGFloat

    init() {
        r = 0.0
        center_x = 0.0
        center_y = 0.0
        arc_end = Angle(degrees: 0.0)
        arc_start = Angle(degrees: 0.0)
        arc_width = 0.0
    }

    var body: some View {
        Path { path in

            path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: center_x, y: center_y), radius: r, startAngle: arc_start, endAngle: arc_end, clockwise: false)
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 100.0, y: 200.0))
            path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: 100.0, y:100.0), radius: r * 2, startAngle: Angle(degrees:90.0), endAngle: Angle(degrees:0.0), clockwise: true)
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:200, y:100))
                }
        .fill(Color(red: 79.0 / 255, green: 79.0 / 255, blue: 191.0 / 255))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`var DrawArc = DrawCircleSegment()`

This code creates an instance/object of type `DrawCircleSegment` So `DrawCircleSegment` is the cookie cutter, `drawArc` (note below on Swift variable naming) would be the cookie.

So then calling `DrawArc(r: CGFloat(50.0 * i), center_x: 100.0, center_y: 100,   arc_start: 0, arc_end: 90, arc_width: 30)` is incorrect, as you are trying to initialise a value from a value rather than a type.

Change

```
DrawArc(r: CGFloat(50.0 * i), center_x: 100.0, center_y: 100,   arc_start: 0, arc_end: 90, arc_width: 30)
```

to

```
DrawCircleSegment(r: CGFloat(50.0 * i), center_x: 100.0, center_y: 100,   arc_start: 0, arc_end: 90, arc_width: 30)
```

If you would like to use an alias to give it a shorter name you can do that:

```
typealias DrawArc = DrawCircleSegment
```

THEN you can DrawArc to initialise it.

Sidenote:

In Swift we use lowerCamelCase style for variable names and only use UpperCamelCase for Types. You should checkout [the Swift style guide](https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide)

Comment: I tried your solution, and indeed it solves the mentioned compiler error. However, it introduces others, and would not address the main issue that I'd like to define many segments of a circle (like a dart-board), all with slightly different properties. Clearly, I need to get a better handle on objects and how to manipulate them. I'll have a look at the style guide, very helpful.

Comment: yeah drawing programatically can be quite a challenge, even for skilled developers. Best to follow along with some tutorials or something similar first so you learn some of the tricks of the trade from experienced developers that might make this easier for you